# 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found using custom xcode build configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

While building RN application using fastlane with custom "Ad-Hoc" configuration i was always getting error like this:

```
[01:24:15]: ▸ In file included from /Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS/RCTLinkingManager.m:8:
[01:24:15]: ▸ /Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS/RCTLinkingManager.h:10:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTEventEmitter.h' file not found
[01:24:15]: ▸ #import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
[01:24:15]: ▸         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[01:24:15]: ▸ 1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and after trying many alternatives I found the problem was with custom Build Configuration in Xcode (in my case were Alpha and Beta). When you compile, apparently Xcode try to use your Target Build Config on Frameworks too, and this causes the error.

**Solution One (Manual)**

Do it manually as beretis answern, but it is hard to mantain, because whenever you add a new Framework/Library you have to set the Build Configs in it or new errors will appear.

**Solution Two (Automated)**

Use react-native-schemes-manager (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-schemes-manager).

This package synchronize your custom Build Configurations in all your Frameworks.

```
yarn add --dev react-native-schemes-manager
```

or

```
npm install --save-dev react-native-schemes-manager
```

In your **package.json** add the postinstall command, so every time you install new package/framework it will sync you Build Configurations.

```
"scripts": {
        "postinstall": "react-native-schemes-manager all"
    },
```

Still in package.json, add a new key with config.

```
   ...

   "xcodeSchemes": {
       "Debug": ["Alpha"],
       "Release": ["Beta"]
   },

   ...
```

In the example above all Frameworks will have 4 Build configurations:

Debug, Release , Alpha (copied from Debug), Beta (copied from Release).

after that, just run:

```
npm run postinstall
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I ended up using custom script too:) So your answer is better :)

Answer (score 1):

Issue can be resolved by adding your custom configuration to all project dependencies (RN ones) in xcode.

[image]